# CSS file is not working in asp.net framework

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am having this problem while making an website on visual studio 12. When I add a CSS file, the features of the CSS is not showing.. sometimes restarting work, otherwise I have to make it all inline. Can anyone help me with it please? It's getting very annoying.

My actual CSS file:

```
body {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}

#info_body {
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#div_left{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}

#div_right{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}
```

The CSS I get by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> on browser(which clearly shows that it is not updated.. I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and also restarted laptop.. same issue):

```
body {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
 }

#divbody {
    height:80%;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:white;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div_left{
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}

div_right{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"             
    CodeFile="selected_search_item.aspx.cs" 
     Inherits="selected_search_item" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
                <title>Selected Searched Item</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="selected_search_item.css" 
/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Body" Runat="Server">
    <div>
        <div id="div_left">
            <div class="info_body">
                <img />
            </div>
            <div class="info_body">
                Information
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_right">
            <div class="info_body">Title</div>
            <div class="info_body">Description</div>
        </div>    
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking in browser development mode (F12 in your browser) whether the css can be found or if the minified css contains your css changes. I think you will have to give some more info about your problem too.

Comment: Check if the CSS file is referred correctly (i.e the file is been loaded from the given location). Also, I would suggest, use inspect element in chrome or whichever browser you are using and see whether the CSS properties and selectors from your CSS files are loaded wherever specified.

Comment: yes, it is referred correctly. Normally after restarting laptop, it works sometimes. It works on the design too.. but when I open the page with a browser (google chrome)  then it's not working..

Comment: @bluedot yes, and the css file on f12 inspect page is separate from actual one.. that is.. it is not uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Check your Site.Master file.  In the `<head>` section, you should put a reference to where your css files are located.  In this case, I have a number of css files located in a folder named Content.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
```

Comment: I am having css files on the same file with master file

Comment: Just checking that you use CssClass for .NET controls and class for other ones, like this:  <td class="question_number">1)</td><asp:Label ID="B1" runat="server" CssClass="question"...

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you did not post code, and there are overt typos (CAn and i t).

Comment: well, the code is very big, so I did not upload.. but wait.. let me edit what my actual css file is and what is on the file that I get when I press f12 on browser.